# Substituir palavras dinamicamente

Tags: c#

Por exemplo, tenho os endereços de arquivos:

> C:/windows/x.exe
>
> C:/windwos/system32/exemplo.exe

Gostaria de substituir o nome do arquivo e a extensão por "", ficando assim:

> C:/Windows/
>
> C:/windows/system32/

Comment: Este endereço estaria armazenado em uma String ?
Mais detalhes por favor

Comment: Estou fazendo uma busca e jogando os resultados numa var:

var subfile = Directory.GetFiles(caminho, "*.csproj", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [Path.GetDirectoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname)

```
var path1 = @"C:/windows/x.exe";
var path2 = @"C:/windwos/system32/exemplo.exe";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path1) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path2) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

**[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wAKnL4)**

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!